# div height at 100% but there is space on top and/or bottom still

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to make a side navigation bar that has a `position: fixed` and a `height: 100%`, but when I try this there is always still space were you can see the background below and or above the `div`. And by the way, I also tried to make the `height` like `1000px` but I still have the same problem.

***HTML:***

```
<div id='navbar'></div>
```

***CSS:***

```css
#navbar {
  background-color:black;
  width:100px;
  height:100%;
  z-index:99;
  position:fixed;
  left:-10px;
  bottom:10px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7oxyvab5/)

Comment: In this case, `bottom:10px` means the bottom of `#navbar` starts 10px up from the bottom of its container. See [`bottom` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom).

Comment: @showdev comment is correct. Anyway maybe you can use [vh](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) instead of percents, it depends on the browsers you are trying to [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that you're setting `bottom: 10px` to push your `#navbar` to the top where you had that `10px` spacing in the first place, which causes the same spacing in the bottom. You can force your element to stretch from start/end of it's parent height by applying `top: 0; bottom: 0;`(you should remove `bottom: 10px;`) to the `#navbar` element.

P.S. `top: 0` is superfluous, however I've set it to demonstrate the concept.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7oxyvab5/1/)

Comment: Hopefully he picks your answer, you were, after all, the first answerer.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/7oxyvab5/2/

## navbar has a bottom of 10px set in the CSS.

```
#navbar {
 background-color:black;
 width:100px;
 height:100%;
 z-index:99;
 position:fixed;
 left:-10px;
 bottom:0px;
}
```